# Convert an array of numbers to Calendar view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I convert an array of numbers into a calendar table view.

For calendar view, I want seven days per row and the dates are not in the array remains disabled.

```js
var missingDates = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, "May", 2021];
var currMonth = missingDates[missingDates.length - 2];
var currYear = missingDates[missingDates.length - 1];
var dayOfWeek = findDayofWeeks(missingDates, currMonth, currYear);
var today = dayOfWeek[dayOfWeek.length - 1];

for (var i = 0; i < missingDates.length - 2; i++) {
  $("#missingCardsWindow").append('<button class="col m-2 border-left border-right btn ' + (missingDates[i] == today ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-light') + ' " onclick="addNewRecordFromMissingCards(' + missingDates[i] + ')">' + dayOfWeek[i] + ' ' + currMonth + ' ' + missingDates[i] + '</button>')
}

function findDayofWeeks(data, currMonth, currYear) {
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var dateString = "";
    var arrayDate = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 2; i++) {
        if (data[i] < 10)
            dateString = currMonth + "/0" + data[i] + "/" + currYear;
        else
            dateString = currMonth + "/" + data[i] + "/" + currYear;
        arrayDate.push(days[new Date(dateString).getDay()]);
    }
    var today = new Date();
    arrayDate.push(today.getDate());
    return arrayDate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="missingCardsWindow"></div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's enough to get you started. There's actually quite a bit to getting a calendar working right, but this satisfies your requirements as stated: dates are in rows of 7 and dates not in the array are disabled. I'll leave it to you to figure out how to start a row on a specific day of the week, pull in Bootstrap or wherever your classes are defined.

I changed quite a bit of your code; I added a variable to capture the month name; I assumed it was the three letter month abbreviation. If not, you'll need to alter the contents of the `months` array. `currMonth` now holds a reference to the 0-indexed month. I added the number of days in the month using a simple method. Then you simply iterate over the days of the month, rendering a button for each, adding the necessary attributes depending on whether the day is in the array or not.

I removed `findDaysOfWeeks` because it produced incorrect and odd results. Instead, I just check if the date being rendered is today's date. Seemed easier.

```js
var missingDates = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, "May", 2021];
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var month = missingDates[missingDates.length - 2];
var currMonth = months.indexOf(month);
var currYear = missingDates[missingDates.length - 1];
var daysInMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth + 1, 0).getDate();
var today = new Date();
today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());

for (var i = 1; i < daysInMonth + 1; i++) {
  $("#missingCardsWindow").append('<button class="col m-2 border-left border-right btn ' + (new Date(currYear, currMonth, i).valueOf() == today.valueOf() ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-light') + ' "' + (missingDates.includes(i) ? ' onclick="addNewRecordFromMissingCards(' + i + ')"' : ' disabled') + '>' + new Date(currYear, currMonth, i).toLocaleString(undefined, {
    weekday: 'long'
  }) + ' ' + month + ' ' + i + '</button>')
}
```

```css
#missingCardsWindow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="missingCardsWindow"></div>
```

Comment: That's all I needed and thank you very much!  I just figured out how to change the starting date of each row.